# how to save output result in text file in python

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

i need to save output result to text file but can't able to save can anyone please help me to solve this problem

```html
def list_checker():
    list_file = input("List of numbers: ")
    usr = input("Username Target: ")
    list = open(list_file, 'r').read().splitlines()
    for num in list:
        try:
            ress = check(num, usr)
            if ress == '__err__':
                print ("Null")
            elif ress.lower() == usr.lower():
                f = open("hit.txt", "a")
                f.write(ress+":"+num)
                f.close()
                print ("Number: {} <{}>".format(num, "OK:)"))
                break
            else:
                print ("Number: {} <{}>".format(num, "OK:)"))
        except:
            print ("Number: {} <{}>".format(num, "OK:)"))
```

and this is output result

```html
Null
Number: 919998802233 <OK:)>
Null
Number: 919722568652 <OK:)>
Null
Null
Null
Number: 917623004040 <OK:)>
Null
Null
Null
```

how to save this output only showed number in result

Answer (score 1):

This should work hopefully ;)

```
def list_checker():
    list_file = input("List of numbers: ")
    usr = input("Username Target: ")
    list = open(list_file, 'r').read().splitlines()
    for num in list:
        try:
            ress = check(num, usr)
            if ress == '__err__':
                print ("Null")
            elif ress.lower() == usr.lower():
                with open("hit.txt", "a") as writer:
                    writer.writelines(f'{ress}:{num}\n')
                print ("Number: {} <{}>".format(num, "OK:)"))
                break
            else:
                print ("Number: {} <{}>".format(num, "OK:)"))
        except:
            print ("Number: {} <{}>".format(num, "OK:)"))
```